# Why i get PayPal API authorization error?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

At first i authorize with this command:

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
   -H "Accept: application/json" \
   -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
   -u "client_id:secret" \
   -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

Then i get access token. With access token i run this command:

```
curl -v -X GET https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/invoicing/invoices?page=1 \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer MY_TOKEN"
```

But i get error:

```
{"name":"AUTHORIZATION_ERROR","message":"Authorization error occurred.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/invoicing/#errors","debug_id":"75bc8ac7b89e1"}
```

Any ideas why? Most of the commands gives me same error. But this command works fine:

```
curl -v -X POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer MY-TOKEN" \
-d '{
  "intent": "CAPTURE",
  "purchase_units": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "value": "100.00"
      }
    }
  ]
}'
```

Any ideas, what i'm missing here?
Thanks, in advance.

Comment: The [docs for v1](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/invoicing/v1/#invoices_get_all) say "Deprecation notice: The /v1/invoices endpoint is deprecated. Use the /v2/invoices endpoint instead. For details, see PayPal Invoicing Basic Integration."

Comment: @ceejayoz ah... i will try. thank you. The funny thing, that i took example from official documentation: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/get-an-access-token-curl/

Comment: If you don't have a very specific reason to be calling the invoicing APIs, don't call the invoicing APIs.